# How does Python pass-by-object-reference work with asynchronous code?

Tags: python, asynchronous

```
foo = { 'bar': None }

for i in range(3):
    foo['bar'] = i
    send_to_async_queue(foo)
```

Can I be certain that the queue processes `0,1,2` every time? If not how to I ensure that it does?

Comment: do you have an example of `send_to_async_queue` ? What sort of library is being used for the `async` part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how `send_to_async_queue` will be implemented.

If you are using something like Celery, the dictionary will be serialized (as json, pickle or other method you choose) before sending to the queue. So, you are safe.

If you are using threads or another in-memory mechanism to hold the queue and process it, all consumers will share the address of this dictionary, and changing it will likely give you problems.

In this case, you can serialize by yourself before putting in the queue; or do a copy of the dictionary using `send_to_async_queue(copy.deepcopy(foo))`.